# Find 'element by' not working in normal execution

Tags: python

I have the following code as part of a data download function in selenium / chrome driver

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("mt-n1").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

When I 'step through' the code it works fine, but in normal execution it fails to action this link on the web page, therefore does not open the next webpage as required by the function

I have inspected the web page and identified the xpath, so I amended the code as follows

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'mt-n1 flex-auto']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

This produces the same result, i.e. only works if I step through the code one line at a time

Hopefully just something obvious I'm not seeing?

The full code is given below for ref.

```
# Download file from github function

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
workDir = r"/C:\Users\Oem\Desktop"

### Set the download directory
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": workDir})

### Open a web-browser for automated control
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://github.com")
driver.fullscreen_window()
time.sleep(5)

assert "GitHub" in driver.title

elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("header-search-input")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("acca-edx/python-practical-automation")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

### Go to the first result.
# Find the results on the page using "mt-n1" and clicking on it.
# Wait for the page to complete.

driver.find_element_by_class_name("mt-n1").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='detection.xlsx']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Find the raw-url to download the file we are after.
driver.find_element_by_id('raw-url').click()

time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried some form of wait before that line? Maybe it needs time to be ready to find or click the element, which would explain why it works in line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

if your code works while going step by step through, it might be that web page needs time to be rendered. try this, it will wait 50 seconds or until the element presence has been located.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'mt-n1')))
except TimeoutException as e:
    # do something if element is not found
```

Comment: This is a good approach. You can also catch TimeoutException to actually know the wait was longer.

Comment: oh yes I totally forgot about catching the timeout exception. thanks I will add it to the answer.